# Floyd Warshall algorithm with maximum steps allowed

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

Is it possible to modify Floyd-Warshall algorithm when solving the shortest path problem for a directed weighted graph with *n* nodes, such that each shortest path have no more than *m* steps? More precisely, for each pair of nodes *i* and *j*, you are about to find the shortest directed path from *i* to *j* that contains no more than *m* nodes. Does time complexity still remain *O*(*n*<sup>3</sup>)?

Comment: I can't think of a way to do it in less than O(n^3m^2) time.  (Essentially: use DP to calculate each value of f(i, j, k, w), where this function represents the shortest path from i to j using only vertices <= k and having total edge count <= w.  The extra m factor is because you need to loop over all m+1 ways to split the edge count on either side of the (k+1)th vertex when you consider paths that go via it.)

Comment: It's slow for the problem I need to solve. Recently, using [min-plus matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-plus_matrix_multiplication), I've implemented m-edges all-pairs-shortest-paths algorithm with maximum of _m_ edges in O(n^3*log(n)) time.

Comment: I'm interested to see your approach -- could you write it up as an answer?  (This is allowed, even encouraged on SO.)  I can't see how you avoid getting m as a factor in the running time with this approach, since each matrix multiplication takes O(n^3) time (or at least O(n^2.something), and you may need up to m of them.  Even so this could still save a factor of m over my way.

Comment: Actually if you meant O(n^3*log(m)) then I can potentially see how it might work: use repeated squaring to drop the max number of iterations from m down to log m.  Is that right?  A write-up would still be awesome :)

Comment: Yup, you'are right! :) Sure, I'll write it then as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meanwhile, I found an *O*(*n*<sup>3</sup>log*m*) algorithm for finding all-pairs shortest paths (ASPP) problem for the graph with *n* nodes such that no path contain more than *m* nodes.

Given two *n* x *n* matrices, say *A* = [*a*<sub>*ij*</sub>] and *B* = [*b*<sub>*ij*</sub>], their [distance product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-plus_matrix_multiplication) is *n* x *n* matrix *C* = [*c*<sub>*ij*</sub>] = *A* x *B*, defined by *c<sub>ij</sub>* = min<sub>1≤*k*≤*n*</sub> {*a*<sub>*ik*</sub> + *b*<sub>*kj*</sub>}.

This is related to the ASPP in the following way. Given weighted matrix *E* of distances in the graph, *E*<sup>*n*</sup> is matrix of all-pairs shortest path. If we add constraint that no path contains more than *m* nodes, then matrix *E*<sup>*m*</sup> is the solution to ASPP. Since calculating power can be found in *O*(log*m*) time, this gives us an *O*(*n*<sup>3</sup>log*m*) algorithm.

[Here](http://www.diku.dk/PATH05/Uri1.pdf), one may find faster algorithms for calculating distance product of matrices in some special cases, but the trivial one *O*(*n*<sup>3</sup>) is enough for me, since overall time is almost as fast as Floyd-Warshall approach.

Comment: Nice.  At first I thought this would only compute the shortest path using *exactly* m edges, but then I realised that it computes the shortest path using exactly m edges *in which any number of those edges may be "self-edges" of cost 0*, so it does in fact compute all shortest paths using *up to* m edges :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes and Yes.

- Each iteration of the algotithm adds a single unit of length of the paths you search for. So if you limit the iterations to m then you find a path of length at most m.
- The complexity will remain O(n^3) in the worst case of m -> n. However, more precise estimate would be O(m * n^2).

Comment: I might haven't got it well, how do I limit iterations to _m_? Do you mean to change the first line of the code from `for k = 1 to n do` to `for k = 1 to m do`? In that case, complexity is reduced as you said, but only first _m_ nodes of the graph are considered when finding the shortest path between each pair of nodes.

Comment: Ah sorry, i was thinking of the Bellman Ford algorithm it seems: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this could be done with a different data structure (one that would allow you to keep track of the number of steps)?

Since usually Floyd-Warshall is done with a connectivity matrix (where matrix [j][k] represents the distance between nodes j and k), instead of making that matrix an integer we can make it a struct that has two integers : the distance between two nodes and the number of steps between them.

I wrote up something in C++ to explain what I mean :

```
#define INFINITY 9999999

struct floydEdge
{
    int weight;
    int steps;
};

floydEdge matrix[10][10];

int main()
{
    //We initialize the matrix
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<10;k++)
        {
            matrix[j][k].weight=INFINITY;
            matrix[j][k].steps=0;
        }
    }

    //We input some weights
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        int a, b;
        cin>>a>>b;
        cin>>matrix[a][b].weight;
        matrix[b][a].weight=matrix[a][b].weight;
        matrix[a][b].steps=matrix[b][a].steps=1;
    }

    //We do the Floyd-Warshall, also checking for the step count as well as the weights
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<10;k++)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                //We check if there is a shorter path between nodes j and k, using the node i. We also check if that path is shorter or equal to 4 steps.
                if((matrix[j][k].weight > matrix[j][i].weight + matrix[i][k].weight) && (matrix[j][i].steps+matrix[i][k].steps<=4))
                {
                    matrix[j][k].weight=matrix[k][j].weight=matrix[j][i].weight + matrix[i][k].weight;
                    matrix[j][k].steps=matrix[k][j].steps=matrix[j][i].steps+matrix[i][k].steps;
                }
                //If the path is not shorter, we can also check if the path is equal BUT requires less steps than the path we currently have.
                else if((matrix[j][k].weight == matrix[j][i].weight + matrix[i][k].weight) && (matrix[j][i].steps+matrix[i][k].steps<matrix[j][k].steps))
                {
                    matrix[j][k].weight=matrix[k][j].weight=matrix[j][i].weight + matrix[i][k].weight;
                    matrix[j][k].steps=matrix[k][j].steps=matrix[j][i].steps+matrix[i][k].steps;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I believe (but I am not completely sure) this works perfectly (always giving the shortest paths for between all nodes). Give it a try and let me know!

Comment: I'm afraid this won't give optimal answers all the time: it might be that for some pair of vertices j and k, even though the shortest path via i requires more than 4(!) steps, there is *another path via i* that requires 4 or fewer steps, but which is still better than all paths between j and k that avoid i.

Comment: E.g. suppose there are 6 vertices j=v1, v2, i=v3, v4, v5, k=v6, with an edge of weight 2 between each vertex and the next, as well as an edge of weight 5 between j and i, and an edge of weight 12 between j and k.  Then the shortest j->k path goes via i and has 5 edges with a total weight of 10, but this has too many edges so your algorithm will ignore it *and all j->k paths that visit i*, preferring the shortest i-avoiding path, which is the single edge j->k with weight 12.  But this ignores the 4-edge path j->i->v4->v5->k with a lower total weight of 11.